# Editing romaji for people without Japanese input

Tags: discussion

Recently I edited [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54613/negative-%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B-too-much-when-to-use-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B-and-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%95%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8B) and [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54612/the-difference-in-use-and-meaning-for-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8F%E3%81%84-%E3%81%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-and-%E3%81%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%84) and converted the romaji to proper Japanese because the OP had left a comment apologising that their Japanese keyboard was broken. I then deleted the comment about the keyboard since it seemed redundant.

Later on I felt guilty because the OP had been told off for not putting in any effort to look up the answers on the site. They probably couldn't do this if they couldn't search in Japanese because the keyboard was broken.

Did I do the wrong thing? If so, what should I do differently next time?

Comment: I would say the OP was given a couple of *gentle reminders* about searching for an answer before asking.  I think "told off" sounds harsh, but the comments don't really seem harsh to me.

Comment: FWIW, when I'm on public computers, I use Google Translate that provides Japanese IME when the "From" language is set to Japanese. So... I believe there are many ways to write in Japanese without using Japanese keyboard. That aside... I don't think converting romaji to its kana/kanji is problematic, as long as it doesn't change OP's intent (e.g. wrong kanji, etc)

Comment: You could edit the romaji, add a comment explaining your motivations for editing, and refrain from deleting any comment at all even if it seems redundant.